# What is the full amount of calculated 5% vat amount $17.8?

Tags: percentages

I need to know the full amount for the 5% vat, which is given as $ 17.8
I need the principal amount on which this 5% is calculated?

Comment: Does any country that uses dollars as its currency unit have VAT?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what a VAT is but it seems you are asking this question:

What is $x$ if:

$0.05x = 17.8$

Well we divide both sides by $0.05$ to get:

$x = 20 * 17.8$

$x = 356$

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that I used the fact that $0.05 = \frac{1}{20}$, dividing both sides of an equation by a fraction is the same as multiplying by the inverse of that fraction. In this case the fractions inverse was $\frac{20}{1}$ which of course simplifies to just $20$

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Got it